# Edit value with jQuery in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel-8

I am trying to write code to edit the value on this edit icon button click but not able to do so.
I want to edit this value without modal and want to save the changes on click of save change button. So please help me.

```html
<p class="inn-admin-title">{{$users->buisness_name}} <span class="pencile-fpu"><button class="add-btn" id="edit-btn" type="button" ><img src="{{asset('assets/img/pencil.webp')}}"><a href="#" class="save-change-b">Save changes!</a></span></button></p>
<input class="semibh" type="hidden" id="reply" value="{{$users->buisness_name}}" style="padding:0px;border:1px;font-size:28px;font-family:AvenirHeavy;margin-bottom:0,0,0px;display:block;box-sizing:border-box;background-color:transparent;color:white">



<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click','.add-btn',function() {
        var profile_id = $(this).val();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do when click add btn and change which value.

Comment: I was saying that if I will take an input type in hidden below the <p> tag then with the help of jquery I want the <p> appears and when I will click on the button the hidden input type appeared .

Comment: Sorry, unable to understand your sentence, what do you mean by **appears**? Are you trying to say that you will add a hidden input and on button click you will grab the value from `data` attributes and change the value of the hidden input?

Comment: yes exactly what i am doing

Comment: I can see hidden input HTML code in your question, please add that in your question.

Comment: "*take an input type in hidden below the <p>*" - there is no `input` in your code?